# Ansible: create dynamically increased numbered directories to a group of hosts

Tags: ansible

I want for example to create 10 directories with incremental number to a group of 5 hosts.
And after the end of the task, the result should be:

```
Server1   Server2   Server3   Server4   server5
 dir01      dir02    dir03     dir04     dir05
 dir06      dir07    dir08     dir09     dir10
```

And if i have to create more directories, the rotation among the servers would be continued.

At the time runing the following task in a group of 5 Hosts:

```
- name: Creates Project's directory in server
  file:
    path: /opt/dir{{item}}
    state: directory
    owner: xxxx
    group: xxxx
    mode: 0775
  with_sequence:
    start=1
    end=10
    format=%02d
```

The result is:

```
Server1   Server2   Server3   Server4   Server5
 dir01     dir01     dir01     dir01     dir01
 dir02     dir02     dir02     dir02     dir02
 dir03     dir03     dir03     dir03     dir03
 dir04     dir04     dir04     dir04     dir04
  ……        ……        ……        ……        ……
 dir10     dir10     dir10     dir10     dir10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a solution that loops over the host that is targeted:

```
- hosts: ...
  var:
    - dirsPerHost: 2
  tasks:
    - file:
        path: /opt/dir{{ '%02x' | format(item) }}
        state: directory
        owner: xxxx
        group: xxxx
        mode: 0775
      delegate_to: "{{play_hosts[ ( (item | int) - 1) % ( play_hosts|length|int ) ] }}"
      run_once: yes
      loop: "{{ range(1, ( ( play_hosts|length|int ) * (dirsPerHost|int) ) + 1) | list}}"
```

This loops over the directorys that should be created like your sample does, but on each run of the loop it chooses a different host to target, going over all targeted hosts in sequence.

The variable "play_hosts" contains all currently targeted hosts. With "play_hosts[ ( (item | int) - 1)]" we select a host corrosponding to the number currently in "item". Then we delegte the current run of the loop to that host, so the task is only executed on it. With "run_once" we make it so the task is only executed once per loop. Otherwise each run of the loop would be executed on the chosen host as many times as there are hosts in "play_hosts".

I've also used "loop" instead of "with_sequence", because that is recommended by ansible. You can read more on that here: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html

With "dirsPerHost" you can choose the number of directories created on each host. This is also the reason for the modulo operation in "delegate_to".

I hope this works for you.

Comment: Hello and thank you for your reply. I have tried to test the playbook but i get the following error:
`ERROR! Unexpected failure in finding the lookup named '{{ range(1, ( ( hosts|length|int ) * (dirsperhost|int) ) + 1) | list}}' in the available lookup plugins`

Comment: You might want to check your "ansible --version". Output on the Setup I tested with:

`ansible 2.7.5
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/home/sshmgmt/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 2.7.12 (default, Dec  4 2017, 14:50:18) [GCC 5.4.0 20160609]`

Also I made an error when copy-pasting my solution, the "DirsPerHost" variable is is not capitaliced properly everywhere.

Comment: Hello, I' ve tested it to day in a test env with Ansible 2.7 and worked as you said.
I' ve made a debug on loop: "{{ range(1, ( ( play_hosts|length|int ) * (dirsPerHost|int) ) + 1) | list}}" and noticed that all servers know about all files.
How each node understands which one of them, should he create?

Comment: Got it! I will have to adjust it for my project which is distribution system, but your idea is very helpfull.
Thank you again.